# Cross thread error updating ListView via BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, backgroundworker

I have a user control that houses a listView. The usercontrol has buttons which open additional forms.
My listView updates perfectly utilising a backgroundworker until I open and close a form? After this I get a cross thread error?

The background worker I used is directly based on this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bcd694e-dc57-4a53-babf-a1ace976ed9f/add-item-to-listview-in-backgroundworker-without-refreshing-the-listview?forum=winforms

How can I make this thread safe?

Comment: can you post the code? Also are you closing and opening the form that starts the background worker?

Comment: The forms that get opened and closed don't execute the backgroundworker. The backgroundworker is part of a method that updates the ListView which sits on the main usercontrol. The code is the same as the link I provided. I read that I may need to call the Completed event on the backgroundworker but not sure what argument to pass since the ProgressChanged already populates the listView.

Comment: The line that fails is the lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = il.Images.Count-1 });

Comment: That should normally get executed on the UI thread so there shouldn't be a problem. I can run the code from that page without any problems, will need to see all the code in order to help. Are you by any chance starting another `BackgroundWorker` from the original `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Think I found the issue. after calling the ShowDialog() to display the form the backgroundworker events get fired on different threads as explained here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3bdd0372-0fa5-49e6-9bc4-ec6d9554f499/backgroundworker-reportprogress-fires-progresschanged-in-a-worker-thread-rather-than-in-the-main?forum=winforms

Comment: Great, very unusual issue by the sounds of it